# Magento, data not insert in model table via observer

Tags: php, magento

I create my custom table in Magento with module and insert the data using 'getModel' in observer but data was not inserted into table also don’t display any error.

My code is below

```
$mycustomorder = Mage::getModel('mycustom/mycustom');
$mycustomorder->setOrderId($mycustomorderData['order_id']);
$mycustomorder->setCustomerId($mycustomorderData['customer_id']);
$mycustomorder->setCustomerEmail($mycustomorderData['customer_email']);
$mycustomorder->setProductId($mycustomorderData['product_id']);
$mycustomorder->setProductPrice($mycustomorderData['product_price']);
$mycustomorder->setProductTax($mycustomorderData['product_tax']);
$mycustomorder->setShippingFrequency($mycustomorderData['shipping_frequency']);
$mycustomorder->setStatus($mycustomorderData['status']);
$mycustomorder->setUniqueId($mycustomorderData['unique_id']);
$mycustomorder->setProductQty($mycustomorderData['product_qty']);
$mycustomorder->setCreatedDate($mycustomorderData['created_date']);
$mycustomorder->setUpdatedDate($mycustomorderData['created_date']);
$mycustomorder->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of things you have to check

first of all check whether the observer event is called or not using echo exit.

If this happen then try to check whether the model is loaded properly or not in your module. also make sure there is entry about your model in config.xml of your module.

Let me know if you have any query

Thanks